# Regular Expression Unterminated string constant Error Javascript

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I have used this regular expression ^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)[a-zA-Z0-9 ?.!*@#'\s]{2,200}$. it should contain special (!*@#) , alpha numeric characters and it should allow maximum 200 characters.
But here i am getting error like unterminated string constant..In google i tried...it is saying dat we need to replce metacharacters like $,* with \
I could not do that..Can anyone help me out

my code is like this

```
$.validationEngineLanguage = {
    newLang: function(){
        $.validationEngineLanguage.allRules = {
            "required": { // Add your regex rules here, you can take telephone as an   example
                "regex": "none",
                "alertText": "This field is required",
                "alertTextCheckboxMultiple": "* Please select an option",
                "alertTextCheckboxe": "* This checkbox is required",
                "alertTextDateRange": "* Both date range fields are required"
            },
            ---
             ----
            "passwordval": {
            "regex":^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)[a-zA-Z0-9 ?.!*@#'\s]{2,200}$,
            "alertText": "* Not a valid password"
            },
            };

    }
};

$.validationEngineLanguage.newLang();
```

I am facing problem in "passwordval":

Comment: Please show actual code (we have no idea if you are even using the correct syntax to create the regular expression) and learn to format questions (there is a GUI, and a help button!).

Comment: Sounds like you have ... wait for it ... a string constant that's unterminated. How about showing the code that gives the error?

Comment: I really hate when people tell me what should and shouldn't be in my password. If I prefer to be stupid and choose a stupid password, or if I want to use special characters (`<` or `é`) I should be able to do so. Adding basic rules (such as, "at least 3 characters") why not, but forcing the user to have special characters is just annoying. What I suggest you to do instead is using a metric on the password and impose a minimum complexity instead: http://www.passwordmeter.com/.  
`MyNameIsColinHebertAndILikeToUseThisPassword` doesn't respect your rules ) but yet is really secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is an error in your Regexp

- change this line

  ```
  "regex" : ^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)[a-zA-Z0-9 ?.!*@#'\s]{2,200}$,
  ```

  to

  ```
  "regex" : "^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)[a-zA-Z0-9 ?.!*@#'\\s]{2,200}$",
  ```

Notice

```
The double quote around the regular expression and the extra \ before \s
```

Comment: This fix doesn't make any sense. '\\s' in `[]` means "either '\' or 's' as a character.

Comment: @ColinHebert, In JavaScript regular expression, the extra "\" is an escape symbol for "\s" which denotes a "space". you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/TMZDf/

Comment: you can't use that between brackets.

Comment: I bet you, it also works in Java. I use an IDE(PhpStorm) and without that escaped \, it will be marked invalid and never gets validated. check the link provided. If ours is wrong provide an alternative.

Comment: Wow, indeed, I actually never did that. My apologies.

Comment: Thanks to everybody.oberror your answer solved my problem.thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
var reExample = new RegExp("^(?=.[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z0-9 ?.!@#'\s]{2,200}$");
```

note the ""

```
reExample.test("dfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdfdfsfsdfsdf");
```

the above yields false

```
reExample.test("dfsfsdfsdfdfsfsd");
```

this yields true

(Assuming you are using javascript)